# How to generate list of words in Libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, word-processor

Basically I need to populate a column with created new words in this format (??P??P) or (??K??K), "?" is wildcard. If possible I would want the 2nd and 5th letters to be vowels. I also want to be able to change the expression (??P??P) to (??X??X), X can be any letter. I tried finding commands for this in "customise menu" and in the "insert menu" options. I tried to find expressions for this in "Regex command" documentation in Libreoffice documentation. I am not a technical person, so I do not have the ability to create scripts for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such "words" are not difficult to generate. To get a random integer use the [**RANDBETWEEN() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060106.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3164669)

Now, using the [**CODE() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3155498), find out the code for the letter "A", add a random number from 0 to 25 to this code, and convert it back to a letter using the [**CHAR() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3149321):

`=CHAR(CODE("A")+RANDBETWEEN(0;25))`

This will give you one random letter.

To get a random vowel letter (or any letter from a predefined list) list all the desired letters in one line and pull out one random letter using the [**MID() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3154589)

`=MID("AEIOU";RANDBETWEEN(1;5);1)`

Letters that should remain unchanged in the template, specify explicitly - just put the letter in quotation marks: "P", "K", "X"

Now you have all the necessary parts for the formula, connect them using the [**CONCAT() function**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_concat.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id741556228031712) or just using the ampersand sign **&**

```
=CHAR(CODE("A")+RANDBETWEEN(0;25)) & MID("AEIOU";RANDBETWEEN(1;5);1) & "P" & CHAR(CODE("A")+RANDBETWEEN(0;25)) & MID("AEIOU";RANDBETWEEN(1;5);1) & "P"
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will be trying it inside the day.